# Implementing ipywidget slider for time

Tags: python-3.x, ipywidgets

I am trying to create a slider for time in Jupyter Notebook using ipywidgets. I would like to take the tabulated experimental data (see figure below) and control the value bounds with the help of a slider. The graph should be a force-displacement graph, evolving in time:

[image]

This is my python code:

```
from ipywidgets import IntSlider, interact, FloatSlider

u = fdat1['C_1_Weg_R4[mm]'].values
f = fdat1['C_1_Kraft_R4[kN]'].values
t = fdat1['S/No'].values

@interact(t = IntSlider(min = 0, max = max(fdat0['S/No'].values)))
def aa_(t):
    plt.plot(f[t],u[t])
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel("force [kN]")
    plt.ylabel("displacement [mm]")
    plt.title("Load-displacement curve for \nexperiment")
```

fdat1 is the name of the tabulated data. I have also considered using "C_1_Zeit[s]" column as my slider values, but these are not integer values.

The problem is that nothing gets plotted, but the slider works and the graph changes scale.

I have been searching online for some time now and would really appreciate some help.

Thank you in advance!

[image: Tabulated experimental data]

Edit:

```
from ipywidgets import IntSlider, interact, FloatSlider

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [np.linspace(0,30, num=30), np.linspace(0,20, num=30), ]).T

df.columns=['A', 'B']

@interact(t = IntSlider(min = 0, max = 21))
def aa_(t):
    plt.scatter(df['A'], df['B'])
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel("force [kN]")
    plt.ylabel("displacement [mm]")
    plt.title("Load-displacement curve for \nexperiment")
    plt.xlim(0, 30)
    plt.ylim(0, 30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically, this should have been the correct code:

```
from ipywidgets import IntSlider, interact, FloatSlider

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


u = fdat1['C_1_Weg_R4[mm]'].values     #loads displacement values from fdat1
f = fdat1['C_1_Kraft_R4[kN]'].values   #loads force values from fdat1


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([u,f]).T   #creates a dataframe

df.columns=['A', 'B']

@interact(t = IntSlider(min = 0, max = df.shape[0]))   #interactive scatterplot with a slider for time
def scatterplot_(t):
    plt.scatter(df.loc[0:t,'A'], df.loc[0:t,'B'])
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel("force [kN]")
    plt.ylabel("displacement [mm]")
    plt.title("Load-displacement curve for \nexperiment")
    plt.xlim(-5, 5)
    plt.ylim(-25, 25)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your plotting function, create a slice of your `results` dataframe that slices based on the slider value.

```py
from ipywidgets import IntSlider, interact, FloatSlider

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

results = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    [np.linspace(0,30, num=30), np.linspace(0,20, num=30), ]).T

results.columns=['A', 'B']

@interact(t = IntSlider(min = 0, max = 21))
def aa_(t):
    df = results.iloc[:t]    # make the slice here
    plt.scatter(df['A'], df['B'])
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlabel("force [kN]")
    plt.ylabel("displacement [mm]")
    plt.title("Load-displacement curve for \nexperiment")
    plt.xlim(0, 30)
    plt.ylim(0, 30)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, your code still has only 2 arguments in the plt.scatter: t and "A". How would you advise to plot values with "A" and "B" coordinates and change the number of plotted points with a t-slider to create a time evolution effect?

Comment: Made an edit to show how you would handle plotting two series against each other.

Comment: I have added improved code in an edit to my question above. Here is what I mean: when I run it, I see a scatter plot of A against B, but do not know how to control the number of points plotted using a slider. The slider for time should basically plot points with indices 0 to t, with t being the slider variable.

Comment: Edited, you had things very close. Use the slider value to slice your dataframe.

Comment: Ok, I have figured it out. I used df.loc to do that. Thank you very much for your help! I will post the working code below.